# Keras methods 'predict' and 'predict_generator' with different result

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have trained a basic CNN model for image classification.
While training the model I have used ImageDataGenerator from keras api.
After the model is being trained i used testdatagenerator and flow_from_directory method for testing.
Everything Went well.
Then I saved the model for future use.
Now i am using the same model and used predict method from keras api with a single image, but the prediction is very different every time I test using different images.
Could you please let me know any solution.

```py
training_augmentation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255.0)
validation_testing_augmentation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255.0)

# Initialize training generator
training_generator = training_augmentation.flow_from_directory(
                                                                 JPG_TRAIN_IMAGE_DIR,
                                                                 class_mode="categorical",
                                                                 target_size=(32, 32),
                                                                 color_mode="rgb",
                                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                                 batch_size=batch_size
                                                              )

# initialize the validation generator
validation_generator = validation_testing_augmentation.flow_from_directory(
                                                                             JPG_VAL_IMAGE_DIR,
                                                                             class_mode="categorical",
                                                                             target_size=(32, 32),
                                                                             color_mode="rgb",
                                                                             shuffle=False,
                                                                             batch_size=batch_size
                                                                          )

# initialize the testing generator
testing_generator = validation_testing_augmentation.flow_from_directory(
                                                                           JPG_TEST_IMAGE_DIR,
                                                                           class_mode="categorical",
                                                                           target_size=(32, 32),
                                                                           color_mode="rgb",
                                                                           shuffle=False,
                                                                           batch_size=batch_size
                                                                        )

history = model.fit_generator(
    training_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=total_img_count_dict['train'] // batch_size,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=total_img_count_dict['val'] // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=callbacks)

testing_generator.reset()
prediction_stats = model.predict_generator(testing_generator, steps=(total_img_count_dict['test'] // batch_size) + 1)


### Trying to use predict method
img_file = '/content/drive/My Drive/Traffic_Sign_Recognition/to_display_output/Copy of 00003_00019.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_file)
img=cv2.resize(img, (32,32))
img = img/255.0
a=np.reshape(img, (1, 32, 32, 3))

model = load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/Traffic_Sign_Recognition/basic_cnn.h5')

prediction = model.predict(a)
```

When I am trying to use predict, every time wrong prediction is coming.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Keras generator` uses `PIL` for image reading which read images from disk as `RGB`.

You are using `opencv` for reading which reads images as `BGR`. You have to convert your image from `BGR` to `RGB`.

```
img = cv2.imread(img_file)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

...
```

Comment: I just tried to convert the color-code but it seems the problem still persists.